# Array as value in a lua table

Tags: arrays, lua, coronasdk, key-value, lua-table

I couldn't find an answer to my question: Can you have an array as value in a lua table?

```
local colors = {"blue" = {0,0,1,1}, "green" = {0,1,0,1}, "red" = {1,0,0,1} , "orange" = {0.5, 0, 0.5, 1}, "black" = {0,0,0,1}, "gold" = {1, 215/255, 0, 1}}
```

I get the error on this line using the corona sdk:

> '}' expected near '='

Comment: syntax error, permissible: ["blue"]= {0,0,1,1} or  blue= {0,0,1,1}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's tables all the way down :-) Yes, tables (including ones indexed like arrays) can be elements of tables in Lua.  This [chapter in the Lua manual](https://www.lua.org/pil/2.5.html) explains the different ways of defining the elements of a table.

In your example, you should not put quotation marks around the key.

```
local colors = { blue = { 0, 1, ...}, green = { ... }, ... }
```

Or you can do:

```
local colors = {}
colors[ "blue" ] = { 0, ... }
colors[ "green" ] = ...
```

Or

```
colors.blue = { 0, ....  }
colors.green = ....
```

The latter is [syntactic sugar](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for the other forms.

Comment: You can have quotation marks around sting keys: `local colors = { ["blue"] = { 0, 1, ...}, ["green with spaces"] = { ... }, ... }`